# Smalltalk new lines?

Tags: smalltalk

I can't get this to work at all:

```
renderContentOn: html
    html form: [
        html textInput
        on: #newEmp of: self.

        html submitButton
        callback: [ self addEmployee: newEmp ];
        text: 'Add Employee'.

        self employeeNames do: [ :eachEmp |  html text: Character cr asString. html text: eachEmp.]
    ]
```

I just keep getting my output on one line. Am I missing something? I've tried several variations of `cr` but none have worked thus far.

Comment: Are you displaying the output in a browser? Then, newlines are ignored. Try using `<br/>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't rely on carriage returns to display your data in the browser. The employee names obviously belong either in a list or a table (you are providing a list of names):

```
html unorderedList: [
    self employeeNames do: [ :eachEmp | 
        html listItem: [
            html text: eachEmp ] ] ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You most certainly want `html break` instead of `html text: Character cr` or any variation thereof. HTML intentionally treats newlines in text as simple spaces.

Other than that, the idea of max-leske to use item lists is much to be preferred.